# Convert array into obj of array with specific key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have this array

```
["all", "GatsbyJs", "React", "GraphQl", "Contentful", "React Native", "Firebase", "Stripe", "Google Api", "Prestashop"]
```

and I would like to convert it to this

```
[
  { value: 'all', label: 'all' },
  { value: 'GatsbyJs', label: 'GatsbyJs' },
  { value: 'React', label: 'React' },
  { value: 'GraphQl', label: 'GraphQl' },
  { value: 'Contentful', label: 'Contentful' },
  { value: 'React Native', label: 'React Native' },
  { value: 'Firebase', label: 'Firebase' },
  { value: 'Stripe', label: 'Stripe' },
  { value: 'Google Api', label: 'Google Api' },
  { value: 'Prestashop', label: 'Prestashop' }
]
```

I know it can be easy to do, but I'm not finding the right path.

This is where I have come up to now

```
function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) rv[i] = arr[i]
  return rv
}

const setupStack = projects => {
  const stack = new Set()

  //   projects.forEach(i => stack.add(i.title))
  projects.forEach(proj => proj.stack.forEach(st => stack.add(st.title)))

  const arr = ["all", ...stack]

  return arr
}
```

I thank in advance who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does exactly what you need.

This method iterates through the array, and allows you to apply some procedure to its elements, so that you get a new array with modified elements.

in your case:

```
["all", "GatsbyJs", "React", "GraphQl", "Contentful", "React Native", "Firebase", "Stripe", "Google Api", "Prestashop"]
.map(item => ({ value: item, label: item }))

// --> [{value: 'all', label: 'all'}, {value: 'GatsbyJs', label: 'GatsbyJs'} ... ]
```

Comment: You can replace `{return { value: p, label: p }}}` with `({ value: p, label: p })` to get a one liner without a weird return statement.

Comment: thank you very much, I don't know how I didn't think about it right away. Maybe I'm just tired, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) because it returns a new array that allows you to determine how the item of the returned array looks like.

```js
function toArrayOfObject(arr) {
  return arr.map(a => ({value: a, label: a}));
}


const testArr = ["all", "GatsbyJs", "React", "GraphQl", "Contentful", "React Native", "Firebase", "Stripe", "Google Api", "Prestashop"]

console.log(toArrayOfObject(testArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = ["all", "GatsbyJs", "React", "GraphQl", "Contentful", "React Native", "Firebase", "Stripe", "Google Api", "Prestashop"];
const obj = arr.map(item => {return {value: item, label: item}})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = ["all", "GatsbyJs", "React", "GraphQl", "Contentful", "React Native", "Firebase", "Stripe", "Google Api", "Prestashop"]

let result = arr.map(elem => {value:elem,label:elem})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = ["all", "GatsbyJs", "React", "GraphQl", "Contentful", "React Native", "Firebase", "Stripe", "Google Api", "Prestashop"];

const testFn = (array) => {
    let mainArray=[];
    let jsonValue;
    for (const element of array) {
        jsonValue=  { value: element, label: element }
        mainArray.push(jsonValue)
    }
console.log('mainArray : ',mainArray);
};
 testFn(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = ["all", "GatsbyJs", "React", "GraphQl", "Contentful", "React Native", "Firebase", "Stripe", "Google Api", "Prestashop"];

array.forEach((obj, i) =>{ array[i] = {value: obj, label: obj} });
console.log(array)
```